# how to migrate Cassandra data from windows server on to LINUX server for Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am not sure if my windows based Cassandra installation will work as it is on Linux based Cassandra nodes.

My data resides on windows Cassandra-DB and plans to shift on to LINUX server in order to use ELASSANDRA now.

Can same data files be copied from Win-OS to Linux-OS in same directories of Cassandra Folders?
As both are with different file system so i have some doubts if that will ever work.

If not what is the workaround to migrate all data?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the files has more to do with the version of Cassandra, rather than the OS.  Cassandra's implementation in Java makes the underlying OS somewhat (albeit not completely) irrelevant.

Each version of Cassandra has a specific format for writing its SSTable files.  As long as the version of Cassandra is the same between each server, copying the files *should* work.

Otherwise, if the Windows and Linux servers can see each other on the network, the easiest way to migrate would be to join the Linux server to the "cluster" on Windows.  Just give the Linux server the IP of the Windows machine as its seed, set the `cluster_name` to be the same, and it should join.  Then adjust the keyspace replication and run a repair.

Answer (score 0):

You should not repair, but stream data from your existing DC with a nodetool rebuild -- [source_dc_name]:

1-Just start all nodes in your new DC with **auto_bootstrap: false** in conf/cassandra.yaml

2-Run **nodetool rebuild** on these nodes

3-Remove **auto_bootstrap: false** in conf/cassandra.yaml

If you start Elassandra in your new DC, Elasticsearch indices wil be rebuild while streaming or reparing, so have fun with it !